# Represent an optional attribute as a C++ class member

Tags: c++, class, schema, code-generation

I am generating C++ code based on a schema. There are entities and each entity contain attribute(s) with each attribute having a corresponding data type. Now the problem is some of these attributes are "optional", meaning that they do not have to be part of the class declaration. However, in C++, something is either a member of class or not a member of class, there is no concept such as "optional data member".

Entities will be the class names, and attributes will be the class members. I am not sure how I can represent attributes marked as "optional" the existing C++ concepts.

Comment: `std::optional` or a pointer?

Comment: what does std::optional do exactly? And it is part of the C++17 spec. I do not think I will be using C++17 spec yet.

Comment: @nmd_07 C++17 is the latest released spec and should be used for new code. And `optional` does exactly what you think.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I would more precisely say "the semantics are exactly what you think". The behind-the-scenes stuff is not obvious at all from the name. Does it heap-allocate or contain the optional object? Does it use sentinel values or require extra space? Is it maybe dependent on `T` (or even customizable)? From a semantic point this doesn't matter but you demonstrated the resulting tradeoffs in your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The canonical answer is [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). It is a semantically accurate way to express a value that might or might not exist in a model.

When creating such a model, for each optional field in a schema, you generate a corresponding `std::optional`-wrapped entry. Then, when deserializing, you can use `std::none` to mark a missing entry, and it during accessing, the client code *must* check for the existence of actual value<sup>1</sup>.

If your objects are large, though, and you want to avoid storing the empty space unnecessarily<sup>2</sup>, the next alternative is `std::unique_ptr`. It has a downside of having pointer semantics, but otherwise remains a valid tool for such a case.

If the members are *very* dynamic, e.g. the possible set is in dozens or hundreds, but typical utilization will see just a few, a key-value store (such as `std::map`) might be a better idea; then you're limited to store just one type of a value. This might be mitigated a bit with `std::variant` being used as the map value type, which gives you one of many possibilities, or `std::any`, which can effectively hold anything while losing type safety.

The decision will ultimately depend on your exact model and usage characteristics.

---

<sup>1</sup> If the client code expects `T`, and the access for a field gives them `optional<T>`, the unwrapping step will/shall check for the existence of an actual value. This is the main reason `optional` is used.

<sup>2</sup> `sizeof(optional<S>)` will most commonly be `sizeof(S) + 1`, but can get bigger because of the alignment rules. [Performance&Memory](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/05/using-optional.html) section of this article shows it nicely.

Comment: @BartekBanachwicz, could please explain what makes `std::optional` suitable in this scenario? How does it really represent an "optional" data member, that may or may not exist?

Comment: i always thought `sizeof(optional<T>) = 1` or close by using some magic, now I wonder even more why it took so long to include it in the standard. I mean if you can live with dynamic allocations then even a `std::vector` containing zero or one elements may be nicer.

Comment: @user463035818 it has been present in Boost library for a quite a while.

Comment: @nmd_07 I know, but boost is not the standard making it slightly less convenient to use it

Comment: @user463035818 - Using `std::vector` may be a nice hack, but it's the wrong abstraction. It ends up forcing the maintainer to keep track of which vectors are real vectors and which are just "optional" fields when working with both. This does not a good codebase make. A unique pointer is closer to an optional as an abstraction.

Comment: @StoryTeller sure, I'd wrap it in a `fake_std17_because_i_have_only_std11::optional` with similar interface as `std::optional` ;)

Comment: @user463035818 You can also wrap `std::unique_ptr`, which is C++11 as well.

Comment: fwiw the [boost docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/performance_considerations.html) even mention a scenario where one should consider not to use optional members

Comment: @user463035818 `std::optional` guarantees that no heap allocation happens - the optional type is directly inside the `optional`. This allows for a tradeoff between heap allocation (speed) or the additional byte/word footprint (size). In any case though, even with a heap allocation, `sizeof(optional<T>)` is only `1` if pointers fit into a single byte on your platform...

Comment: @MaxLanghof my misunderstanding was that `optional` provides you an advantage in size, but its the other way around

Comment: @StoryTeller • History ALMOST repeats itself.  (1972) does `Foo*` point to a single Foo or NULL, or to an array of Foo or NULL?  (2018) does `std::vector<Foo>` contain zero-or-one Foo, or zero-or-more Foo?

Comment: @Eljay - Only shows you can never truly kill a bad idea

Comment: ...fly-by-comment :) - a small example (or link to) demonstrating usage of `std::optional`, `std::none`, etc, would be wonderful ...

Comment: @slashmais added.