# If statement inside Struct Declaration C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, struct, preprocessor-directive

I have a doubt regarding structs and if statements in C++

For the sake of simplicity, I have created a sample code to explain my intention

```
int var = 10

struct example{
    int a;
    int b;
    if(var > 8){
        int c;
    }
};
```

I have a codebase which uses similar kind of code as above. Commenting out the if portion does not give any errors.
My question is

- Could if statements be put in struct declarations?
- If not, what is the possible remedy for this, since if statment is mandatory.

Note: I cannot use #if,#else directives nor std::optional or other standard libraries to mitigate this, so please help me find another solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Represent an optional attribute as a C++ class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533640/represent-an-optional-attribute-as-a-c-class-member)

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Only use the tag appropriate to the language you are using. (I fixed in favour of C++ since the title mentioned C++ but not C.)

Comment: *"a codebase which uses similar kind of code as above"* - how "similar" is it, and more important does it do what you want? If so, is there some reason *not* to follow that pattern?

Comment: What's that supposed to do? It does not even compile, so yes it gives "an error". Even if this would make any sense, `int c` is obviously in the scope of the `if` and vanishes afterwards.

Comment: "I cannot use the techniques the language offers to do this" ... not sure what sort of answer you are expecting tbh

Comment: @WhozCraig The reason to not follow this "pattern" is because it does not work, obviously.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Sorry, in my naivety, when the OP claimed "I have a codebase which uses similar kind of code as above." I was led to believe they had code that actually worked, which did something similar, not identical, to that posted here.

Comment: @WhozCraigOK, sorry, I see. But control flow statements like `if` cannot be used like that in the member definition scope of a struct. The "similar code" is obviously doing something entirely different. It's probably only "similar" in the sense that it is C++ syntax.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I'm keenly aware of the language semantics. It feeds my wonderment as to why the OP's "similar" code isn't sufficient. If it is because it isn't really similar, but rather *identical* to this failed attempt, so be it, but it does foster one's intrigue as to the sense of even mentioning it if that were the case. I hope that makes sense. The OP has seemingly gone utterly silent on this regardless, so we may never know.

Comment: Why don't you just leave c there, leave it unused. Unless you're doing things like reading value from file, it should be fine have an extra variable that does nothing (although it takes extra space).

Comment: One more think, I think you should clarify what you're trying to archive. Eg. what's the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't use if statement inside your struct or class definition. Instead, for condition declaration, you can use #if directive.

```
#define var 10
struct example {
    int a;
    int b;
    #if var > 8
        int c;
    #endif
}
```

This will work.

'#if' is a compiler directive (pre-processor directive). if statement on the other hand is runtime statement.

Other than this there is no other way!

Comment: Nice, except for the whole *"Note: I cannot use #if,#else directives to mitigate this"*

Comment: @WhozCraig well he can use them, he just chooses not to for unclear reasons

Comment: This is the only sensible solution to tackle what the OP *might* have wanted to do. It's still unclear what was intended, because having a control flow statement like `if` in a struct definition makes zero sense.

Comment: you're missing an `#endif`

Comment: @M.M somehow, I hesitate to believe the OP actually has a choice in the matter; from that description, it certainly seems they *would* use the preprocessor, and understand it would work, but are under some restriction not to (ex: an academic exercise).

Comment: @WhozCraig Maybe, but the task cannot be solved in the way the OP claims. That he states that this gives "no error", when it's trivial to see (and test!) that this does not even compile, shows there are more fundamental problems to solve for the OP than only this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int var = 10;
     if(var>10){
                struct example{
                int a;
                int b;
                int c;

             };
            }else {
                    struct example{
                    int a;
                    int b;

                  };

                }
      cout<<"Hello World";

       return 0;
}
```

There are multiple ways to address your problem one way of achieving is shown.

We cannot add if Statement in the Structure.